# How to get token from URL and redirect back to app after instagram authorization?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I use this for authorization:

```
Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent viewIntent =
                    new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=token"));
            startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    });
```

After the user logs in and successfully authorizes he gets redirected to the REDIRECT_URI which has an added token like `http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

**My problem is:**

1) How do I redirect the user back to my app, when instagram only allows the REDIRECT_URI to have the `http:// or https://` schema and therefore I can't use the `myapp://` method.

2) How do I retrieve the token from the URL back to my app?

I know similar questions have been posted before and I read hundreds of them but none seems to be answered, as far as I understood.

Answer (score 1):

Use webview to login and use the webview onload event to read the `access_token` hash fragment